# Google Classroom - userProfiles.get not returning the verifiedTeacher attribute

Tags: api, google-classroom

When fetching the [userProfiles.get](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/userProfiles/get) method, it does return a [UserProfile](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/userProfiles) object but it doesn't seem to return the **verifiedTeacher** attribute.

Here is my response from the Google API Playground here:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-length: 297
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
X-content-type-options: nosniff
X-goog-trace-id: 112a56fbf6e2b530785ebb084b9ab298
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
Server: ESF
-content-encoding: gzip
Cache-control: private
Date: Sun, 21 Jan 2018 12:36:21 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303338; quic=51303337; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="41,39,38,37,35"
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-location: https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/userProfiles/me
{
  "photoUrl": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg", 
  "emailAddress": "3gtest@xxxxx.sa.edu.au", 
  "id": "106492323808275670", 
  "name": {
    "fullName": "Staff3 gTest", 
    "givenName": "Staff3", 
    "familyName": "gTest"
  }
}
```

Can anyone give me some tips to try to get the verifiedTeacher attribute returned from this API as described in the documentation?

Thanks

Comment: Are you a member of  [G Suite for Education domain](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/userProfiles#UserProfile)?

Comment: Well, this account can log into Google Classroom, but I'm not entirely sure if it is a G Suite for Education domain. It's not really clear what the different between the 2 are. Shouldn't the API still return the verifiedTeacher attribute, with the value being false ?